# twitter-bootstrap glyphicons bug with firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, web

Currently using bootstrap 3.0 for a project, I've got a weird bug with firefox:
Instead of the glyphicons I get some weird characters.. when I refresh it goes back to normal..

[image: weirdness]

Here is how I use glyphicons:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock white"></i> 
<a href="#" class="active"> Deposit</a>
```

is this the right way to use them or is there something special I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid way of using one of the bootstrap 3 glyphicon halflings.  I'm not sure that the `white` class does anything anymore, but that's not important I don't think.

If the issue occurs in other browsers, then you should ensure that the glyphicons fonts are being downloaded by your browser.

Comment: I'm testing it with firefox 21.0 which is not the latest version .. can you see the link in the description?

Comment: Can you test with another browser, just to see if the behavior is the same?

Comment: Is your font hosted on a CDN or another domain?